# Cleaning data automatically

Tags: preprocessing

Do you use automatic cleaning tools for data?

I mean something similar to h2o.ai's *auto ml* function but applied to preprocessing data.
Or do you always clean data 'by hand'.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning data largely varies from data to data. Considering you are talking mostly about *unstructured data*, it can be of two types, namely **Image data** and **text data**. The process of cleaning both these data depends on the type of goal required to be achieve using these. A little brief process could be explained as follows:

- **Image data**: While performing convolutional neural network on the data, the process of feature extraction from the data is automated. Specific pre-processing need to be carried out aiming it to the target. This includes:

  - Keeping the data set close to the actual data on which the model is to be tested.
  - Removing any unnecessary images that do not co-ordinate with the corresponding label.
  - Resizing the images as per the model requirement.
- **Text data**: Text data has a robust procedure for of pre-processing consisting of *Removing stop words, tokenizing, lemmetizing the tokens* etc. At times when we are using the *word to vec* approach, we need to convert the text tokens to their corresponding word-vectors.

Generally functions designed for these processes are fed into the pipeline and so individually every entry is not required to be processed in a similar way.

There are some papers and blogs I would suggest you to read: [Towards automated patient data cleaning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.00096.pdf) , [Turn Messy Data into Tidy Data](https://machinelearningmastery.com/data-cleaning-turn-messy-data-into-tidy-data/)